# Put link into php

Tags: php

i want to put link into a sentence that are stored in variable..
how to put the link?
because i try use echo..but it did not work..

here is my code:

```
if($_POST['rb_elt_accommodation']=="Yes") 
$accomodation_val .= "Participants must deal directly with the hotel. Please call the hotel direct at +xxxxxx. Details on accomodation booking are available"echo '<a href="http://abc.com">here</a>.'";
```

Comment: first of all you have to learn how to format your code, to make it fit into screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['rb_elt_accommodation'] == "Yes")
{
    $accomodation_val .= 'Participants must deal directly with the hotel. 
                          Please call the hotel direct at +xxxxxx. 
                          Details on accomodation booking are available 
                          <a href="http://abc.com">here</a>.';
}
```

Note how I changed your echo quote char from `"` to `'`
This was to allow for `"` inside your html string.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel : yes.it help me a lot

Comment: @Beginner I know it helped you. But what did you *learn* from it?